# Formal way to find the number of vertices of a graph given the degree sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have the following degree sequence: {4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

Is there an algorithmic or a simple formula/heuristic to find the number of vertices/edges in the graph?

Comment: You can simply count the vertices: there’s one for each term of the degree sequence. Then you can use the handshaking lemma to get the number of edges.

Comment: I am told however that this graph has 9 edges, despite there being 11 terms in the degree sequence set.

Comment: There’s no contradiction there. Take another look at my previous comment. (And yes, it does have $9$ edges.)

Comment: OH, I apologize. I confused vertices with edges.

Comment: That’s okay; I figured that that’s what had happened.

Comment: Ah, thank you. So just to make sure I understand why 9 was the correct answer, sum of all elements in degree sequence is 18. Sum = 2*E, so 18/2 = 9 edges. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.